# How to make sure I get an Integer from a EditText

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
EditText value = ( EditText )findViewById( R.id.editbox );
Integer int_value = Integer.valueOf( value.getText().toString() );
```

It works great when there are a number in the EditText, but it FC my application when it is empty or have text, etc.

How can I make sure that int_value have/are a number?  I also tried parseInt but with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  try {             
Integer int_value  = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

add `android:inputType="number"` in your `EditText` declaration in your xml file.

Comment: This only solves one of the problems. If the EditText is empty this won't help at all.

Comment: If it is empty then how will you get the values from the edittext.

Answer (score 1):

When a string which cannot be parsed is served as input to `Integer`'s `valueOf`, it throws a `NumberFormatException`. Simply surround it with a `try catch` block to handle such cases:

```
Integer int_value = null;

try {
    int_value = Integer.valueOf(value.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // here you can handle the case where the text wasn't an integer
}

// carry on...
```

Answer (score 0):

set inputType="number" in xml
and check for empty value in code

```
if(!"".equals(value.getText().trim()) && value.getText().trim()!= null) {

  //sure, input is not empty and is a number.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v,boolean hasFocus)
                {
                    //check for emptiness
                    if(editText.length()==0)
                    {
                        editText.setError(error_required);
                    }
                    else if(!numberValidation(editText.getText().toString()))
                    {
                        editText.setError("Only Numbers");
                    }
                }
            }
            );
```

In main.xml add,

```
EditText tag, android:numeric="integer/number/decimal"
```